# AJAX function onBeforeUnload doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am tracking the length of time an individual user is on my site. In order to achieve this I am logging the timestamp of when the user first loads the page and each time they click on a new page.

A brief summary:

Database table (time_on_site):

```
+-------+-----+-----------+----+
| start | end | unique_id | id |
+-------+-----+-----------+----+
```

1. INSERT timestamp in `start` when session is created (just the once).
2. UPDATE the timestamp in `end` each time the `onbeforeunload` event is fired.

This works fine for tracking the time they're on the site while browing pages, but when they leave the site (i.e., browser is closed/exited), a problem is occuring and I don't know how to find it. Basically the `end` record just isn't getting updated with the timestamp. It's like the AJAX function is not getting called properly since the browser is closing. I have set `async` to false in the AJAX call, but that does not help.

Why is this function not working when the user closes the browser, but works all other times the `onbeforeunload` event fires?

**Edit**

Error was simply that there was no check for `else if($_GET['when'] == "end")`.

Here's my code:

index.php:

```
// If the session DOES NOT EXIST, make it and set it to TRUE.
if(!isset($_SESSION['new_visit']))
{
    $_SESSION['new_visit'] = true;
}

// If the session is TRUE, make it false.
if($_SESSION['new_visit'] == true)
{
    $this->db->store_visit();

    $_SESSION['unique_session_id'] = hash("sha512", uniqid("", true) . uniqid("", true) . uniqid("", true));

    $_SESSION['new_visit'] = false;
}
```

At the bottom of index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    if(window.addEventListener)
    {
        window.addEventListener("load",         function(){log_time("start");}, false);
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(){log_time("end");  }, false);
    }

    function log_time(time)
    {
        var xmlhttp = "";
        var session = "<?php echo $_SESSION['unique_session_id']; ?>";

        // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari.
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        // IE6, IE5.  
        else
        {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/application/logtime.php?session=" + session + "&when=" + time, false);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

</script>
```

logtime.php:

```
//session_start();

require "database.php";

$db = new Database();

$unique_id = $_GET['session']; //$_SESSION['unique_session_id'];
$time      = time();

if($_GET['when'] == "start")
{
    if($get_rows = $db->mysqli->query("SELECT 1 FROM time_on_site WHERE unique_id = '$unique_id'"))
    {
        $rows = $get_rows->num_rows;
    }

    // If rows were afffected, the unique ID has already been stored so we must UPDATE. This happens each time a page is refreshed.
    if($rows >= 1)
    {
        $db->mysqli->query("UPDATE time_on_site SET end = '$time' WHERE unique_id = '$unique_id'");
    }

    // Else if the rows affected were 0, we must INSERT a new record. This happens once per session (visit).
    else
    {
        $db->mysqli->query("INSERT INTO time_on_site(start, unique_id) VALUES('$time', '$unique_id')");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need `onunload` instead `onbeforeunload`?

Comment: In `logtime.php` you need to either get the `$unique_id` variable from the session (`$_SESSION`), or validate it to prevent a trivial SQL injection attack. Also, `logtime.php` does nothing when `$_GET['when'] != "start"`

Comment: Note that Opera doesn't support the `onbeforeunload` event, and I don't see why the (more widely supported) `onunload` event couldn't be used here. Though it looks like your AJAX call is being made, in general a good way to check this in Chrome is to open up the Developer Tools and click Network (and use the Record button to preserve HTTP calls after you've navigated to a new page).

Comment: @GeorgeP For crying out loud, George! You solved it, no action was being taken for `$_GET['when'] != "start"`. I've got to start checking my code more thoroughly, these questions of mine lately have been simple errors that any amateur could fix. Also, `$_SESSION` was being used originally instead of `$_GET`, but I considered the posibility that the session was unset/destroyed before the AJAX function was called and changed it so the session ID was echoed into JavaScript. Thanks George.

Comment: @George88, no worries, it happens to all of us! I've moved my answer to an actual answer so you can accept it. And as I said, if you have to get the session ID from the user, be aware that a malicious user could call your PHP script with any session ID they want, which your script would send straight to the database, leading to a major security hole. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($_GET['when'] == "start")
{
    // ...
}
```

This conditional is missing an `else` branch, so if `$_GET['when'] != "start"`, nothing will happen.